# NASM assign values

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm, instruction-set

i have a tiny question regarding to the following statement. Assume rax and rbx are pointing towards a valid memory address.

```
mov byte [rax], [rbx]
```

Why isn't that statement valid?

Comment: You should review the [instruction set architecture reference](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) for the [MOV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) instruction. The limitation is in the processor. There is no `MOV` encoding that moves from one memory location to another directly. You have to do it in two moves. Move the data from the source memory location to a register then the register to the destination memory location.

Comment: PUSH/POP can move from memory to memory but they have one implicit argument (the stack). [MOVSB/MOVSW/MOVSD/MOVSQ](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq) can be used to move data but the SRC and DEST memory addresses are implicit as well ([ESI/RSI] to [EDI/RDI])